# soft viterbi decoder not working properly

Tags: matlab, telecommunication, viterbi

I have been working on viterbi decoder in matlab2009 on simple 1/2 rate convolutional encoder.
Here is my code

```
trel = poly2trellis(3,[7 5]);
msg = [ 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 ];
code = convenc(msg,trel);
% Traceback Length 
tblen = 5;
ucode = real(awgn(1-2*code,tblen,'measured'));

dcd = vitdec(ucode,trel,tblen,'cont','unquant');
```

According to this input code
i am getting the code = 00 11 10 00 01 10 01 11 11 10 00 10 11 00 11
which is correct
but talking about the dcd which is output after viterbi decoder is coming incorrect
i.e 000000101110010. which is far different from my msg input.

guide me where i am going incorrect

Comment: It looks *shifted* to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decoded output depends on the type of `opmode` Input you selected.

In case of `cont`, there is a delay in the output equal to `tblen` number of symbols whereas there are 'term' and `trunc` modes as well.

You can compare the initial `msg(1,end-tblen)` symbols with `dcd(1,tblen+1:end)`. They are same!

You may check `vitdec` at Matlab help.

Comment: Yes, i have realized my mistake earlier .Still thanks for answering. :)

Comment: Ashish Sharma can you help me with soft input soft output matlab code.